# R lookup between 2 data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

suppose i have two data frames

```
df1=data.frame(item=c(rep("a",2),rep("b",3),"c","NA",rep("d",4)),
product=paste0("prd",seq(1:11)))
df2=data.frame(item=c("b","d"), price=c(10,20))
```

for df1, i need to add a col to indicate if it's in df2 item col, as well as for each row, indicate how many products are there, unless it's na,like this

```
item product#
a    2
a    2
b    3
b    3
b    3
```

how should i get the product count repeat for each row?

for lookup i'm using

```
df1$hasDF2=ifelse(is.na(match(df1$item,df2$item)),"N","Y")
```

is there a more efficient alternative?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 df1$productNo<- with(df1, ave(seq_along(product), item, FUN=length))
  df1$productNo
  #[1] 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 4 4

 df1$hasDF2 <- c("N", "Y")[(!is.na(match(df1$item, df2$item))) +1]
 df1$hasDF2
 #[1] "N" "N" "Y" "Y" "Y" "N" "N" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y"
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[,c("produtNo", "hasDF2") := list(.N, "N"), 
              by=item][item %in% df2$item, hasDF2:= "Y"]
```

#### Update

For the `unique` count, you could do:

```
 #creating a dataset with duplicate products
 df1 <- data.frame(item=c(rep("a",2),rep("b",3),"c","NA",rep("d",5)),
 product=paste0("prd",c(1:11,11)))

 setDT(df1)[,c("productNo", "hasDF2") := list(length(unique(product)), "N"), 
          by=item][item %in% df2$item, hasDF2:= "Y"]
```

Comment: and if need unique count instead of count, how should i modify FUN=length? thanks

Comment: @santoku Do you want to summarize the count instead of having the count in each row?

Comment: i want to have the count in each row, but imaging products have duplicates for each item. anyway FUN=length is good enough